# Can you give access from the program in Visual Basic Studio 2010 Express to the temp folder in Windows 10?

Tags: vb.net, temp

I'm doing some application in Visual Basic Studio 2010 Express, which uses the Temp folder in Windows 10. Open when I want to use this path I get an error: "Access to path denied: C: \ .......". Can I give some permission to the application to use this path? It's best that the application should be licensed and not that I should, for example, dig in Regedit, because no one who will have my application will be able to give it permission itself.

Comment: If your application doesn't have permission to access the directory, then it's certainly not going to have permission to alter the permissions on the directory either.  If it could, that would be a big hole in the OS security.  The only option is to elevate the privileges of your application, either at startup, every time it runs, via a manifest setting, for instance, or by having the application relaunch itself with elevated privileges.  When you do so, it will obviously prompt the user to allow it or possibly even enter their administrator password, depending on how you do it.

Comment: What directory are you trying to open? See [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Temp")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable) and [Path.GetTempPath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath). Better avoid hard-coded paths to default resources, especially user-related: a user may change them without sending you an e-mail.

Comment: Or simply `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp`